# Проверка наличия установленного пакета на bash

Tags: linux, bash, debian

Поставили такую вот задачку: нужно написать скрипт, который будет проверять, установлены ли apache2, mysql и php и рядом с каждым пунктом писать `installed` или `not installed`. Сам код прошу не писать! А лучше разжевать, как это сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дистрибутив? Проверка пакетов в разных дистрибутивах идет по разному, у меня на убунту срабатывает вот это, не знаю насколько правильно

```
dpkg -s sqlite3 | grep Status
```

**UPD** По быстрому накатал вот такой скрипт, в принципе пашет, но есть проблема с тем что сообщение о том что пакет не найдет это ошибка и она остается в выводе, скорее всего я использую не ту команду, поищите как определить состояние пакета с помощью dpkg, apt-get или aptitude, все они в дебиане есть по умолчанию, принцип скрипта скорее всего не поменяется

```
#!/bin/bash

#$1 - поданая на вход скрипта переменная
I=`dpkg -s $1 | grep "Status" ` #проверяем состояние пакета (dpkg) и ищем в выводе его статус (grep)
if [ -n "$I" ] #проверяем что нашли строку со статусом (что строка не пуста)
then
   echo $1" installed" #выводим результат
else
   echo $1" not installed"
fi
```

Comment: +1, дистрибутив нужно знать. Может и вовсе rpm юзать надо  :-)

Comment: ну, в принципе можно попытаться нащупать сами файлы пакетов, а для апача с мускулом еще и демоны проверить, но это несколько неверно ИМХО, да и вопрос все-таки был про пакеты :)

Comment: они могут быть установлены, но не запущены :-)

Comment: Дистрибутив - debian

Comment: @klopp, я потому и не написал про это в ответе. @Сяськаа Для дебиана то же самое, убунту на нем строится

Comment: Ну как я понял эта команда проверяет установлены эти пакеты или нет,верно?
А как примерно скрипт написать? Чтобы получилось как в условие?

ЗЫ Я только начал это изучать,поэтому такие глупые вопросы. Прошу прощения

Comment: дополнил, дальше уже надо копать, с ходу не могу сказать. В принципе, вывод даже можно раскрасить

Comment: #!/bin/bash
requiredPackages=(apache2 mysql php)<br />

for curPackage in ${requiredPackages[*]}
do
if dpkg -s "$curPackage" &> /dev/null; then
echo "Package $curPackage is installed"
else
echo "Package $curPackage is not installed"
fi
done

Вот и решение :)

Answer (score 0):

Кроме предложенного выше `dpkg -s` вы можете использовать `apt-cache policy`:

```
$ apt-cache policy jenkins
jenkins:
  Installed: 1.542
  Candidate: 1.542
  Version table:
 *** 1.542 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

А вот так в случае, если пакет не установлен:

```
$ apt-cache policy sl
sl:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.03-17
  Version table:
     3.03-17 0
        500 http://someserver.domain/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
```

Таким образом, начать можно с `apt-cache policy php | grep Installed`

---

> Скрипт, который будет проверять

Если вдруг вам нужно это проверять на многочисленных хостах, посмотрите в сторону ansible:

```
ansible hostgroup -i production -m shell -a 'apt-cache policy mypackage | grep Installed'
```

То же самое:

```
ansible hostgroup -i production -m shell -a 'dpkg -s mypackage | grep Status'
```