# Скрипт, проверка наличия установленного пакета и его версии

Tags: ubuntu, bash, debian

Доброго времени суток, уважаемые участники.
Помогите реализовать bash-скрипт, который должен работать в ubuntu.
Тут [был вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/141577/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-bash,) по смыслу похожий, но не совсем то что нужно.
Хотелось бы так же выяснить установлен ли пакет и если установлен, так же выяснить версию установленного и сверить эту версию с доступной на сайте, если версии совпадают, вывести сообщение в диалог  zenity >> что у вас установлена последняя версия..ОК
Если на сайте имеется новая версия то вывести в диалог  zenity >> что имеется новая версия V /значение.

Comment: 99% работы в том ответе уже сделано (`dpkg -s ...`). А что такое "*сверить эту версию с доступной на сайте*"? На каком сайте?

Comment: "99% работы в том ответе уже сделано" Да, я так и писал что "Тут был вопрос по смыслу похожий, но не совсем то что нужно."  а по поводу -"что такое "сверить эту версию с доступной на сайте"? На каком сайте?" то если версия отличается с сайтом программы - допустим на сайте программы уже доступна новая версия, вывести эту доступную новую версию в диалог zenity

Comment: И чего конкретно там не хватает?  Про dpkg и apt-cache расписано, а как отправить сообщение в диалог - это в любом гугле написано...

Comment: В планах, применять этот скрипт не к одной конкретной программе, просто не в курсе пока как реализовать весь процесс, просто там надо будет еще сделать так что если версии совпадают завершать работу скрипта, если доступна новая версия продолжать работу скрипта с последующей установкой доступной версии

Comment: Так что конкретно непонятно? Как запускать эти программы с разными пакетами в аргументах командной строки? Очень просто: `apt-cache policy один_пакет`, `apt-cache policy второй_пакет`,  `apt-cache policy третий_пакет`... Или даже так: `apt-cache policy один_пакет второй_пакет третий_пакет`. Как вытащить версии из вывода?

Comment: Скрипт : 1- установлен ли вообще пакет -"name" , 2 - если установлен, проверяет версию пакета,  3- выяснив версию, сверяет ее с сайтом программы, 4 если версии совпадают выводит диалоговое окно zenity, что установлена последняя версия и работа скрипта завершается по OK, если версия отличается вывод диалога что доступна новая версия и в этом же диалоговом окне, вопрос, установить - нет ? Примерно так  должен работать скрипт.

Comment: 1-3 есть в том посте. 4 - в гугле. Единственное что мне непонятно - что значит "*сверка с сайтом программы*". Сверка с репозиторием? Тогда это есть в apt-cache. С каким-то сторонним сайтом? Тогда это нереализуемо в принципе.

Comment: Скачивать нужно deb-файлы или исходники? А то может быть поможет `uscan`?

Answer (score 2):

Вот простенький пример, выводит версию установленного пакета и версию в репозитории. В случае отсутствия пакета - пустоту:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ -z "$1" ]; then
  echo "\nUsage: $0 package_name"
  exit 2
fi

apt-cache policy "$1" | \
  tr -d '\n' | \
  awk -F' ' \
  '{printf("%s\n\tcurrent version: %s\n\trepo version: %s\n", $1, $3, $5);}'
```

---

> со сторонних сайтов выкачивать со страницы доступные релизы

Короткий ответ: не получится.

Длинный:

Вам придётся *вручную* перебрать *тысячи* пакетов (даже если ограничиться теми, что уже стоят), и для каждого:

1. Выяснить, есть ли у него отдельный сайт.
2. Можно ли на этом сайте скачать готовый пакет по прямой ссылке.
3. Для каждого сайта написать отдельный парсер, выдирающий информацию о версиях и ссылку.

Даже если эта работа будет проделана (а это далеко не пара десятков человеко-часов), вы охватите лишь небольшую часть пакетов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, на счет репозиторий то нужно не из репозиторий а к примеру со сторонних сайтов выкачивать со страницы доступные  релизы, к примеру через wget -O- https://...../releases | grep -o '[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]' | uniq > releases  а далее из файла releases сравнивать с установленной версией, так как с репозиториями нет смысла , в этом скрипте, все уведомления через репозитория и так через менеджер доступны, вот почему и пришел к идеи реализации этой затеи, есть варианты так ?  еще раз спасибо за ваш ответ, жаль нет баллов отметить ответ полезен.

Comment: Немного поразмыслив, решил подробно описать, в общем этот скрипт если реализовать, то его можно делать как шаблон, к примеру я устанавливаю пакет не из репозиторий, с какого то проекта и в дальнейшем хочу отслеживать новые релизы, при появление новой версии скрипт сообщает нам о новой версии и далее предлагает его установить, так что думаю можно отказаться от сообщений что "у вас установлена последняя версия", если так то скрипт ничего не выводит и прекращает работу, если есть новая версия, только тогда  выводит диалог через zenity  с предложением об установке.

Comment: См. обновление ответа.